# HDMI TV Issues with Acer V3-571 laptop

Tags: nvidia, sound, resolution, hdmi, tv

Im a complete Linux novice. Iv installed Mint today on my laptop. So far so good.
However Im having a few teething issues with regards to my HDMI connection.

When I connect to my TV via HDMI the TV displays the image with a section missing all the war around. The image fits the whole panel but it is not the complete image. 
In win 7/8 I was able to go into advanced settings and make a custom resolution which solved this.

The second issue is that there is no sound to the TV. Right clicking on the sound icon in the system tray doesn't reveal anything. If I click configure there is no option to switch between audio devices (Laptop/TV...). Ideally I had hoped this would happen automatically as it did in the last 2 versions of Windows.

Is there a way to set Ubuntu/Mint up to solve these issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About sound:
Left click sound icon and do you see "Sound Settings"?
On Ubuntu in Output tab you can see
Play Sound though:
In my case I have "HDMI/DisplayPort" option which I set up for sound from TV screen.

Also I have installed GNOME Tweak Tool.
Maybe you need to install also some Tweak tool on Mint Linux distribution as well.